# Checking if function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble proving that this is a well-defined function.

$f: C_2 \times C_3 \to C_3$, where $f(h^r,k^s)=(12)^r ∘ (123)^s$

I also want to show if it is a group morphism or not.

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: A functional arrow is simply ‘\to’.

Comment: Thanks, @Randall

Comment: Is the codomain supposed to be $S_3$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the codomain is supposed to be $S_3$ and not $C_3$:

To prove a function is well-defined, you need to show that if $(h^{r_1},k^{s_1})=(h^{r_2},k^{s_2})$, then $f(h^{r_1},k^{s_1})=f(h^{r_2},k^{s_2})$.  Suppose that $(h^{r_1},k^{s_1})=(h^{r_2},k^{s_2})$, then $r_1=r_2+2a$ and $s_1=s_2+3b$.  Then 
\begin{align}
f(h^{r_1},k^{s_1})=(12)^{r_1}(123)^{s_1}&=(12)^{r_2+2a}(123)^{s_2+3b}=(12)^{r_2}(12)^{2a}(123)^{s_2}(123)^{3b}\\
&=(12)^{r_2}(123)^{s_2}=f(h^{r_2},k^{s_2}).
\end{align}

Hence, the function is well-defined.  The comment about associativity doesn't make much sense, unless you want to put some group structure on functions.